# RSS for Android

Tags: android, rss

I downloaded the source code from IBM for RSS reader implementation.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

But when I am running the application, it displays nothing. Please tell me the problem with this application or suggest me a good and simple tutorial for the same.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to setup an implementation of a SAX parser but the hard part is to be able to parse any and every feed under the sun.

You need to cater to all formats RSS 1, RSS 2, Atom etc. Even then you will have to contend with poorly formatted feeds.

I had faced similar problems in the past so decided to do my feed parsing on a server and just get the parsed contents. This allows me to run more complex libraries and parser which I can modify without pushing out updates for my app.

I have the following service running on AppEngine which allows for a much simpler XML / JSON parsing at your end. There is a fixed and simple structure to the response. You can use this for parsing

http://evecal.appspot.com/feedParser

You can send both POST and GET requests with the following parameters.

feedLink : The URL of the RSS feed response : JSON or XML as the response format

Examples:

For a POST request

curl --data-urlencode "feedLink=http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml" --data-urlencode "response=json" http://evecal.appspot.com/feedParser

For GET request

evecal.appspot.com/feedParser?feedLink=http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage&response=xml

My android app "NewsSpeak" uses this too.

Comment: I'd like to know how you did the feedParser on the site, in PHP, Java.  I like that offloading the parsing to something more robust than the phone since XML parsing is labor intensive and SAX parsing blows compared to SimpleXML...